# How to bundle legacy jQuery plugins with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to optimize some pages for a web app I develop and the first obvious thing is to bundle the js libraries together. However I am failing to achieve this with webpack. As an example I have a `Feed.html` page which uses the libraries below (keeping the list short for brevity):

- plugins/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.js
- plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/2.0.11/moment.min.js
- plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/2.0.11/daterangepicker.js

I would like webpack to create a bundle with these files and call it `Feed.js` so I can then include this single js file instead of each of them individually.

As most of the plugins we use are legacy ones they do not abide by the CommonJS/AMD/UMD patterns and are meant to be used as simple `<script>` tags on the page. Given that information I have then found webpack's `script-loader` but it does not seem to be doing anything.

## Page/Feed.js

```
require("script!../plugins/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.js");
require("script!../plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/2.0.11/moment.js");
require("script!../plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/2.0.11/daterangepicker.js");
```

## webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        Feed: './Page/Feed.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: './Bundles/'
    },
};
```

## Bundles/Feed.js

```
    /******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
    /******/    // The module cache
    /******/    var installedModules = {};

    /******/    // The require function
    /******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

    /******/        // Check if module is in cache
    /******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
    /******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

    /******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
    /******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
    /******/            exports: {},
    /******/            id: moduleId,
    /******/            loaded: false
    /******/        };

    /******/        // Execute the module function
    /******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

    /******/        // Flag the module as loaded
    /******/        module.loaded = true;

    /******/        // Return the exports of the module
    /******/        return module.exports;
    /******/    }


    /******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
    /******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

    /******/    // expose the module cache
    /******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

    /******/    // __webpack_public_path__
    /******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";

    /******/    // Load entry module and return exports
    /******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
    /******/ })
    /************************************************************************/
    /******/ ([
    /* 0 */
    /***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

        __webpack_require__(1)(__webpack_require__(2))

    /***/ },
    /* 1 */
    /***/ function(module, exports) {

        /*
            MIT License http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
            Author Tobias Koppers @sokra
        */
        module.exports = function(src) {
            if (typeof execScript === "function")
                execScript(src);
            else
                eval.call(null, src);
        }

    /***/ },
    /* 2 */
    /***/ function(module, exports) {

        module.exports = "require(\"script!../plugins/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.js\");\r\nrequire(\"script!../plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/2.0.11/moment.js\");\r\nrequire(\"script!../plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/2.0.11/daterangepicker.js\");\r\n\r\n"

    /***/ }
    /******/ ]);
```

It seems webpack is just outputting the `Page/Feed.js` as a string in the bundle.  How can I achieve this concatenation of the files?

Comment: Did you ever resolve. I'm just starting on this journey and facing the same problem with limited experience on how to deal with it